# Why is FLASK not running on given route?

Tags: flask, routes, recommendation-engine

I am not able to get http://127.0.0.1:5000/movie Url from the browser.
Every time it gives 404. The only time it worked was with URL from hello world.

I am trying to run a recommender system deployment solution with flask, based on https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/build-a-movie-recommendation-flask-based-deployment-8e2970f1f5f1.

I have tried uninstall flask and install again but nothing seems to work.

Thank you!

```
from flask import Flask,request,jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
import recommendation

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app) 
        
@app.route('/movie', methods=['GET'])
def recommend_movies():
    res = recommendation.results(request.args.get('title'))
    return jsonify(res)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(port = 5000, debug = True)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  When you run the above code with debug set to True, and you go to http://127.0.0.1:5000/movie,  what exactly do  you see in the terminal that started flask run?

Comment: @ewong what appears is : serving Flask app 'rec.py' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 166-656-719

Comment: Please include that in your question.  That said, so when you go to http://127.0.0.1:5000/movie,  you don't get any additional log?

Answer (score 0):

http://127.0.0.1:5000/movie
be careful not writing '/' after movie like http://127.0.0.1:5000/movie/